# How change scale text

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, text-object, command-line

in command bpy.ops.object.text_add scale not worked    #scale=(0.005, 0.005, 0.005)

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.text_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(2, 1  ,0), scale=(0.005, 0.005, 0.005), rotation=(1.5708, 0, 1.5708))
ob=bpy.context.object
ob.data.body = "test" #row[0]
```

Comment: one the one hand it appears to be a bug.  However if I use a method like ```primitive_cube_add(...scale=(2.0,1.0,0.5)...)``` the resulting objects ends up with a scale of (1,1,1) but with Dimensions changed to accord with my desired scale, i.e., Object:: apply :: scale.  The question is whether you want to report this as a bug (perhaps you should try), or ask the question in this forum: "If I apply scale of a text object, the result is not as expected" (try this yourself).

Comment: use `radius=0.5`

Comment: the scale has 3 axes ...